# React Native Navigation Refresh List Screen on back

Tags: reactjs, react-native

React Native Navigation Refresh List Screen on back:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Order List', {
  order_id: this.state.order_id,
  order_status: this.state.od_status,
})
```

Comment: please provide more solid description and/or more code of the screen(s)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achive isn't clear, but if  want to modify your list of data when going back to your previous screen you could simply use `useEffect` and modify your list in there.

**Note:** Your list has to be stored in a local state otherwise the screen wouldn't re-render when updating the list and youl would see no changes on your screen.

Answer (score 0):

better description of the problem would be helpful, but this is general solution for class based components:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._unsubscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
        this.loadDataFunction();
    }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this._unsubscribe();
}
```